# Is the universal enveloping algebra functor exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, lie-algebras

The universal enveloping algebra is a functor from Lie algebras to unital associative algebras, and is left adjoint to the functor which sends a unital associative algebra to a Lie algebra with bracket given by the commutator. Being a left adjoint, the universal enveloping algebra construction is obviously right exact, but is it left exact? It would be nice if it was, but I have a feeling it isn't. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Lie algebras to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Provided you ar working over a fiel, you have the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem. Can you use that?

Comment: I would observe, however, that the universal enveloping algebra construction provides also a functor from Lie algebras to cocommutative Hopf algebras which is left adjoint to the primitive functor. Furthermore, if we restrict to connected cocommutative Hopf algebras over a field of characteristic zero, it becomes an equivalence by Milnor-Moore Theorem

Comment: I was confused by the claim the functor is right-exact. It is not, because unital associative algebras do not form abelian category.
$$
0\to\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}\to 0
$$
does not result in exact (no exactness at $U(\mathfrak{g})$) sequence:
$$
U(\mathfrak{h})\to U(\mathfrak{g})\to U(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h})\to 0.
$$

Comment: @dsh A functor is left- (resp. right-) exact if it preserves finite limits (resp. colimits). Whether or not a category is Abelian doesn't matter. Left adjoints are always cocontinuous and in particular right exact. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+functor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; it already fails to preserve finite products. It sends a product of Lie algebras to a tensor product of algebras.

Comment: Ok thanks! Well that is good to know as well. So it's a strong monoidal functor.